# Is this the best way to convert multi dimensional array of Byte to List of Byte-arrays?

Tags: c#

I am having a method which must return List of Bytes as follow:

```
 public List<byte[]> ExportXYZ(IPAddress ipAddress, WebCredential cred)
```

Inside above method I am calling third party method which returns a multi-dimensional byte array:

```
 byte[][] tempBytes = xyzProxy.ExportCertificates();
```

So now I need to convert `byte[][]` to `List<byte[]>`.

I wrote below code

```
private List<byte[]> ConvertToSigleDimensional(byte[][] source)
{
    List<byte[]> listBytes = null;

    for(int item=0;item < source.Length;item++)
    {
        listBytes.Add(source[i][0]);
    }

    return listBytes;
}
```

I feel this is not a good way of coding. Can anyone help me to write proper code for the conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method doesn't return a list of `byte` - it returns a list of `byte[]`, of byte arrays.

Since your input is an array of byte arrays, you can probably simply convert from one to the other.

With LINQ:

```
  byte[][] arr = ...;
  List<byte[]> list = arr.ToList();
```

Without LINQ:

```
  byte[][] arr = ...;
  List<byte[]> list = new List<byte[]>(arr);
```